# PlayFramework validation error message customisation

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I have a simple HTML form in a play template with a field definition as below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h3>Description</h3>
    <label for="description" class="sr-only">Description
        @for(error <- form("description").errors) {
        <p>@error.message</p> }
    </label>

    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="description"></textarea>
</div>
```

In the corresponding model, I have `@Required` annotation on description field like this:

```
@Required(message="model.description")
public String description;
```

In `conf/messages`, the following is defined:

```
model.description=Please provide a description
```

When I run the application and supply an empty value, the empty value is marked as an error by the framework. However, the error message that I see is (generated HTML from view->source in browser):

```
<label for="description" class="sr-only">Description
<p>model.description</p> 
</label>
```

So it seems like the message key in the annotation is not being resolved.What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help in advance.

*Update*: I added the following in the controller to see if the conf/messages file is being picked up:

```
System.out.println(Messages.get("model.description"));
```

It generated the following output in the console:

```
Please provide a description
```

So, the messages file is being picked up. But the form still display the lookup key.

Comment: How do you bind the form from to request? How/where do you use `bindFromRequest()`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing this line:

```
<p>@error.message</p>
```

To:

```
<p>@Messages.get(error.message)</p>
```